# "Hooking" monad binds using monad transformers?

Tags: haskell, serialization, monad-transformers, resumable

I'm interested in the problem of resumable (and serializable) processes and saw that there is a Haskell package ("Workflow") that seems to do just that: take an existing computation (of type `IO ()`) and wrap it in a monad that make the computation resumable.

My rough idea of how that should work is that you consider an element of type `IO ()` as an expression built-up from "binds", and that the monad transformer (i.e. `lift`) should map binds to binds, thus allowing you to insert some pre- or post-processing steps into your expression. However so far I have not been able to make this work.

So my I guess my question would be, is my idea reasonable? If not, how does the Workflow package do its magic?

To fix ideas, below is what I've tried:

```
-- Instance of MonadTrans for WorkflowT
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans, lift)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)

-- Definition of the Workflow monad transformer
newtype WorkflowT m a = WorkflowT { runWorkflowT :: m a }

instance MonadTrans WorkflowT where
    lift = WorkflowT

-- Instance of Functor for WorkflowT
instance Functor m => Functor (WorkflowT m) where
    fmap f (WorkflowT ma) = WorkflowT $ fmap f ma

-- Instance of Applicative for WorkflowT
instance Applicative m => Applicative (WorkflowT m) where
    pure = WorkflowT . pure
    (WorkflowT mf) <*> (WorkflowT ma) = WorkflowT $ mf <*> ma

-- Instance of MonadIO for WorkflowT
instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (WorkflowT m) where
    liftIO = WorkflowT . liftIO

-- Instance of Monad for WorkflowT
instance MonadIO m => Monad (WorkflowT m) where
    return = pure
    WorkflowT ma >>= f = WorkflowT $ do
        a <- ma
        let WorkflowT mb = f a
        b <- mb
        liftIO $ putStrLn "Checkpointing after executing step..."
        return b

-- Example computation representing multiple steps
compositeComputation :: IO ()
compositeComputation = do
    putStrLn "Executing step 1..."
    putStrLn "Executing step 2..."
    putStrLn "Executing step 3..."

-- Lift the composite computation into the WorkflowT monad             
transformer
liftedComputation :: MonadIO m => WorkflowT m ()
liftedComputation = liftIO compositeComputation

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Run the lifted computation in the base monad
    runWorkflowT liftedComputation
```

My expectation (hope) would have been that the line "Checkpointing..." would be printed after every "step", but it is not.

Comment: Expand your question with what you've tried and what didn't work? As it is it is very difficult for me to understand what you mean. In particular I don't understand how inserting pre- or post-processing steps follows from a lift that maps binds to binds.

Comment: Do you know the Workflow package? What it does is what I try to reproduce.

Comment: It seems like `WorkflowT` is not a lawful MonadIO, because indeed `do liftIO a; liftIO b === liftIO (do a; b)` should hold.

Comment: This law is precisely why I thought such an "intrusive lifting" should be possible, i.e. if you interpret this as a definition you could (perhaps) recursively define lifting.

Comment: If a law abiding Workflow-like monad would exist then that would indeed mean you should be able to do such intrusive lifting, but I doubt that it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your code ever uses the bind of WorkflowT.  `compositeComputation` may be composite in the IO monad but it's wrapped in a single WorkflowT.

If you do something like this it works.

```
runWorkflowT (do liftIO (putStrLn "a")
                 liftIO (putStrLn "b")
                 liftIO (putStrLn "c"))
```

The Workflow package requires you to do something similar - if you look at the [example here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Workflow-0.8.3/docs/Control-Workflow.html) it wraps each individual IO action with `step`, not all of them together.

(Maybe you also want to move the logging before `b <- mb`.  It seems weird for it to come after both actions rather than in between.)

Comment: Yes, you are right: I just realized that in the examples the "Workflows" are really constructed as such, using the "bind" of Workflow explicitly, as in your code above. I thought it was able to do that automatically, i.e. lift a term of type `IO ()` which is constructed using binds to a term of type `WorkflowT IO ()` in such a way that the resulting expression has the same binding structure, and I couldn't understand how it was able to do that. My bad!

Comment: My "idea" of how that was supposed to work is that you could use the transformer law `lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)` to compute what the lift of a bind should be and kind of "pattern match" on bind expressions. But that doesn't seem possible, I think. And you are right about the placement of `b <- mb`, that was a mistake.

Comment: But maybe it is possible to achieve something like that using rewrite-rules...

Comment: @BlenderBender The meaning of the transformer law you quote is that those two forms are supposed to be indistinguishable from the outside; it isn't supposed to **matter** whether you bind and then lift the result or whether you lift the separate elements and then bind the results. Either way should have exactly the same observable outcome. So if your idea *depends* on using the transformer to compute from one expression to the other because they have different effects, you are by-definition violating the law.

Comment: How am I violating the law if I use the law to define the lifiting?

Comment: @BlenderBender `lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)` can't be a definition in Haskell (since you can't pattern match a value to tell that the `>>=` operator produced it, nor "unapply" it to get the original arguments back). It's a property that your actual definition is required to satisfy, and you can't possibly do that if you intend that `lift (m >>= f)` *needs* be transformed into `lift m >>= (lift . f)` in order to have the correct effects; either form is required by the law to have the same effects.

Comment: It's not but perhaps it could be made into one using rewrite rules.

Comment: @BlenderBender That sounds like an extremely bad idea, even if you could. You would be writing an incorrect `lift`, and hoping your rewrite rule changes it to code with *different* results; any time the rule doesn't fire you have a correctness bug (not just a performance one). Other code that works with general transformers (polymorphically) expects to be able to rely on that law (that's the whole point of having laws); such code doesn't think it needs to preserve which form was used because they both should have the same effect. But the rewrite rule won't apply to that generic code.